# Заблокировал собственный IP Lunux

Tags: linux

На сервер шел жуткий SYN-FLOOD и с целью закрыть все SYN коннекта ввел следующую команду (просто из топика с похожими симптомами):

`lsof -p 2556
netstat -a -n | grep -E "^(tcp)" | grep -v "*" | cut -c 45-68 | awk -F\: '{print$1}' | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | grep -v "0.0.0.0" | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -20`

Теперь не могу подключиться к Mysql со своего же сервера, но с внешнего подключается без нареканий.
Уже прогуглил каждую отдельную команду и пытался понять в чем дело, но каждая из них будто бы ничего связанного с блокировкой не делает и поэтому как исправлять понятия не имею.

Answer (score 1):

А где сама блокировка?

Этой командой Вы заблокировали топ 20 работающих соединений в этом списке оказался и mysql.

Куда вы этот список скормили? Перезагрузитесь если не сохранили правила фаервола гдето.